# Run a raw text file in MPS

Tags: java, dsl, lexer, parser-generator, mps

I am developing a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) using the [MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/) tool. However MPS being a projectional editor does not allow to run programs written in plain text files. The code has to be written in the MPS editor or in IntelliJ Idea via a plugin. The whole concept of MPS is tied to a specific IDE.

Is there any work around for this or should I revert to other lexer/parser based tools such as JavaCC or ANTLR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "workaround" for this is the use of a conventional parser, that builds an MPS-style AST.

The projectional editor gets MPS out of all kinds of parsing troubles (consider an MPS-style editor for C), at the price of not being able to parse.  Every technology choice has benefits and costs.